# How to setup Squid Proxy Server on ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: server, internet, security, proxy, squid-deb-proxy

I had tried using the Ubuntu wiki guidelines to set it up on test server, and it worked. Though I would appreciate if anyone can provide me with few other links as this time I am going to install it on a live server which has few other services configured and those services need internet.

So frankly don't wanna mess with it, however I have to configure the proxy server on it as it's client requirement. I need a few links which can give me info of details of each step involved in installation and configuration of Squid Proxy Server and what activity each step will perform?

If you would like to suggest new Proxy server part than Squid then the requirements are below:

1. Must have a web console to configure and perform daily changes, alterations etc.
2. OpenNMS should be able to monitor it.
3. should be able to granular configurable, for future requirements.

Please feel free to correct the question or ask for more info where required, as I'm not that great with the Language :P

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Squid is a proxy server and web cache daemon.  It has a wide variety of uses, from speeding up a web server by caching repeated requests; to caching web, DNS and other computer network lookups for a group of people sharing network resources; to aiding security by filtering traffic.

A very great step by step tutorial could be find here http://microstutorial.com/setting-up-squid-proxy-server-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

In short steps are:

Step 1

Setup an Ubuntu box with 2 Lan* interfaces

Step 2

Configuring the LAN interfaces as Automatic (DHCP) or Manual.

Step 3

update software list

```
sudo  apt-get update
```

Step 4

Install squid

```
sudo apt-get install squid
```

Step 5

configuration

For full details of these steps refer to link provided above.